# How can I use file upload with MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I used file upload to insert the file path on DB and the uploaded file on file on the project directory , I added my code but It didn't worked well.

```
<div class="editor-field create-Bt2">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active)
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="create-Bt ">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </div>
```

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Category category)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var fileName = "";

            var fileSavePath = "";
            var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
            fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("../../Uploads/" +
              fileName);
            uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);


            db.Categories.Add(category);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(category);
    }
```

Comment: "It didn't work well". What went wrong? Are you not getting a file, doesnt it hit the action, what is happening?

Comment: *It didn't worked well.* Please describe precisely what happend! Error code, actual behavior, etC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your form

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In your Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file) {

  if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
    file.SaveAs(path);

    // save the path to your table 
    // db.???

    db.SaveChanges();


  }

  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: I can't see how you've changed it. the point of my answer it that if you want to receive a file you MUST have a parameter of type HttpPostedFileBase that is called whatever your file input control is called.

Comment: I used Razor also I didnot post all completed project ,the page has input button

Comment: but you understand that my answer is how you achieve what you are trying to do. You should mark it correct and upvote it if you agree.